# JavaScript Duration of animation isn't exact

Tags: javascript, setinterval, duration

First of all I want to mention two things,
<s>**One:** My code isn't perfect (esspechially the eval parts) - but I wanted to try something for my self, and see if I could duplicate the jQuery Animation function, so please forgive my "bad" practices, and please don't suggest that I'll use jQuery, I wanted to experiment.</s>
**Two:** This code isn't done yet, and I just wanted to figure out what makes it work badly.

So the animation runs for about 12 seconds while the duration parameter I entered was 15 seconds, What am I doing wrong?

```
function animate(elem, attr, duration){
  if(attr.constructor === Object){//check for object literal
    var i = 0;
    var cssProp = [];
    var cssValue = [];
    for(key in attr) {
          cssProp[i] =  key;
          cssValue[i] = attr[key];
    }
    var fps = (1000 / 60);
    var t = setInterval(function(){
      for(var j=0;j<cssProp.length;j++){
        if(document.getElementById(elem).style[cssProp[j]].length == 0){
          //asign basic value in css if the object dosn't have one.
         document.getElementById(elem).style[cssProp[j]]= 0;
        }
        var c = document.getElementById(elem).style[cssProp[j]];
        //console.log(str +" | "+c+"|"+cssValue[j]);
        if(c > cssValue[j]){
            document.getElementById(elem).style[cssProp[j]] -= 1/((duration/fps)*(c-cssValue[j]));
        }else if(c < cssValue[j]){
            document.getElementById(elem).style[cssProp[j]] += 1/((duration/fps)*(c-cssValue[j]));
        }else if(c == cssValue[j]){
            window.clearInterval(t);
        }
      }
    },fps);
  }
}
  animate('hello',{opacity:0},15000);
```

**html:**

```
  <p id="hello" style="opacity:1;">Hello World</p>
```

*Note: I guess there is a problem with the*

> (duration/fps)*(c-cssValue[j])

*Part or/and the interval of the setInterval (fps variable).*

**Thanks in advance**.

Comment: First remove the eval parts, please. Use `var style = document.getElementById(elem).style[cssProp[j]];` instead of that ugly str building.

Comment: First things first, debugging through that much `eval` is going to be so incredibly painful.  Clean that up first... As a reminder, `eval("foo("+str+")")` is the same as `foo(str)`.  And `eval("obj."+ propName)` is the same as `obj[propName]`.  Those two rules should allow to rip out nearly every eval there.

Comment: eval is evil with an a instead of an i

Comment: I've edited it, now with no evals... anyone knows why this happens?

Comment: What is `k`? It's not declared or set anywhere in this snippet.  And given that it's part of the tween calculation that seems important.

Comment: @AlexWayne, Sorry my bad, I tried to apply a constant to make the intervals somewhat more reasonable, I've edited it out. Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not gonna try and refactor that and figure it out, cause it's pretty wonky.  That said... a few things.

**Don't rely on the value you are animating to let you know animation progress**

In general your approach is unsound. You are better off keeping track of progress yourself.  Also, as a result of your approach your math seems like it's trying too hard, and should be much simpler.

Think of it like this: your animation is complete when the time has elapsed, not when the animated value seems to indicate that it's at the final position.

**Don't increment, set**

Floating point math is inexact, and repeated addition cumulation like this is going accumulate floating point errors as well.  And it's far more readable to make some variables to keep track of progress for you, which you can use in calculations.

```
animatedValue += changeOnThisFrame // BAD!
animatedValue = valueOnThisFrame   // GOOD!
```

**Don't do the positive/negative conditional dance**

It turns out that `10 + 10` and `10 - (-10)` is really the same thing.  Which means you can always add the values, but the rate of change can be negative or positive, and the value will animate in the appropriate direction.

**timeouts and intervals aren't exact**

Turns out `setTimeout(fn, 50)` actually means to schedule the fn to be call at least 50ms later.  The next JS run loop to execute after those 50ms will run the function, so you can't rely on it to be perfectly accurate.

That said it's usually within a few milliseconds.  But 60fps is about 16ms for frame, and that timer may actually fire in a variable amount of time from 16-22ms.  So when you do calculations based on frame rate, it's not matching the actual time elapsed closely at all.

**Refactor complex math**

Deconstructing this line here is gonna be hard.

```
document.getElementById(elem).style[cssProp[j]] -= 1/((duration/fps)*(c-cssValue[j]));
```

Why for more complex break it up so you can easily understand what's going on here. refactoring this line alone, I might do this:

```
var style = document.getElementById(elem).style;
var changeThisFrame = duration/fps;
var someOddCalculatedValue = c-cssValue[j];
style[cssProp[j]] -= 1 / (changeThisFrame * someOddCalculatedValue);
```

Doing this makes it clearer what each expression in your math means and what it's for.  And because you didn't do it here, I had a very hard time wondering why `c-cssValue[j]` was in there and what it represents.

**Simple Example**

This is less capable than what you have, but it shows the approach you should be taking.  It uses the animation start time to create the perfect value, depending on how complete the animation should be, where it started, and where it's going.  It doesn't use the current animated value to determine anything, and is guaranteed to run the full length of the animation.

```
var anim = function(elem, duration) {

    // save when we started for calculating progress
    var startedAt = Date.now();

    // set animation bounds
    var startValue = 10;
    var endValue   = 200;

    // figure out how much change we have over the whole animation
    var delta = endValue - startValue;

    // Animation function, to run at 60 fps.
    var t = setInterval(function(){

        // How far are we into the animation, on a scale of 0 to 1.
        var progress = (Date.now() - startedAt) / duration;

        // If we passed 1, the animation is over so clean up.
        if (progress > 1) {
            alert('DONE! Elapsed: ' + (Date.now() - startedAt) + 'ms');
            clearInterval(t);
        }

        // Set the real value.
        elem.style.top = startValue + (progress * delta) + "px";

    }, 1000 / 60);
};

anim(document.getElementById('foo'), 5000);
​
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/DSRst/

Comment: Regarding "floating point errors", they will be insignificant as they occur at about the 15th significant digit. It's more likely that carless rounding will cause the animation to not proceed smoothly or over the correct interval.

Comment: I followed your solution, and it worked with only a ~7ms error. Thanks!

Comment: @RobG yeah, it's likely not a huge factor here but why have a less accurate number when you can have a more accurate one?

Answer (score 3):

You cannot use `setInterval` for accurate total timing.  Because JS is single threaded and multiple things compete for cycles on the one thread, there is no guarantee that the next interval call will be exactly on time or that N intervals will consume the exact duration of time.

Instead, pretty much all animation routines get the current time and use the system clock to measure time for the total duration.  The general algorithm is to get the start time, calculate a desired finish time (starttime + duration).  Then, as you've done, calculate the expected step value and number of iterations.  Then, upon each step, you recalculate the remaining time left and the remaining step value.  In this way, you ensure that the animation always finishes exactly (or nearly exactly) on time and that you always get exactly to the final position.  If the animation gets behind the ideal trajectory, then it will self correct and move slightly more for the remaining steps.  If it gets ahead for any reason (rounding errors, etc...), it will dial back the step size and likewise arrive at the final position on time.

You may also need to know that browsers don't always support very small timing amounts.  Each browser has some sort of minimum time that they will allow for a timer operation.  Here's [an article](http://www.adequatelygood.com/2010/2/Minimum-Timer-Intervals-in-JavaScript) on minimum timer levels.

Here's [an article](http://www.schillmania.com/content/projects/javascript-animation-3/) on tweening (the process of continually recalculating the step to fit the duration exactly).

I'd also suggest that you look at the code for doing animation in some libraries (jQuery, YUI or any other one you find) as they can all show you how this is done in a very general purpose way, including tweening, easing functions, etc...

Comment: Thanks for the solution, you both had the same (~) solution, but Alex's was a bit more comprehensive, thanks anyways!

Comment: +1 very important to use setTimeout and correct the time to the next step on each iteration. A test for the minimum clock step can be included (in some browsers it's 15ms or so) so it can be allowed for.